# JQuery on blur from one of the input but not focus on those input

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

There are two input elements:

```
<input name="in1">
<input name="in2">
```

I would like to do something when the mouse is BLUR from one of the INPUT, but not FOCUS on those two INPUT.  Something like:

```
$("#main_part").on(
   // "blur","input[name=in1], input[name=in2]",
   // "not focus", "input[name=in1], input[name=in2]",
    function(){
         alert("working"); 
 });
```

How to solve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=in1]").blur(function(){
    alert("1 working");
});
$("input[name=in2]").blur(function(){
    alert("2 working");
})
```

Comment: When [name=in1] on blur, it may focus on [name=in2]